# Drop-down menu items being clipped by iframe

Tags: css

I'm using an iframe to embed an Uberflip collection on a webpage, but the iframe seems to be clipping the drop-down nav menu above it and I'm not sure how to fix it.

http://www.eaglesflight.com/training-resources

There are 8 listed items under the training navigation header, but it clips mid-way through the sixth item. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what iframe are you talking about? i cant find an iframe on that page?

Comment: nevermind, i just found it